# MongoDb delete query

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to delete something from my mongoDb database based on the _id and i swear anything else gets deleted except what I want. I'm using a codeigniter library this is the function:

```
public function delete($collection = "")
 {
    if(empty($collection))
    {
        show_error("No Mongo collection selected to delete from", 500);
    }

    try
    {
        $this->db->{$collection}->remove($this->wheres, array('fsync' => TRUE, 'justOne' => TRUE));
        return(TRUE);
    }
    catch(MongoCursorException $e)
    {
        show_error("Delete of data into MongoDB failed: {$e->getMessage()}", 500);
    }

 }
```

And I'm doing this to delete

```
$this->mongo_db->delete('videos', $data = array('_id' => $id));
```

It definitely deletes but not what I want. I'm new to mongo so where should I check for errors ?

Comment: I met similar issue. The CodeIgniter mongodb library seems cannot delete anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be caused by many elements.

- check if your $id is a string or a **MongoId** (if you use php official mongo driver, I assume its php code, just use `new MongoId($id_as_string)`; (It should be an MongoId)
- you can also test with `safe` option (without sync) and check what you obtain as result (**"safe"** query return array not a boolean)

Answer (score 0):

That function expects one argument, which is the name of the collection, you call it with two. Check the docs/source to see how you can specify the where document.